# Version Control for NetLogo Models

Tags: version-control, netlogo

I'm wondering if anyone has a good method for version control of NetLogo models, other than simply keeping old versions in numbered directories.  My models use a number of .nls files so any method would need to include those as well.

Answer (score 4):

Robin is right: any version control tool should do. NetLogo files (both `.nlogo` and `.nls`) are just text files.

If you are not familiar with version control tools like `git`, let me state emphatically that getting to know one is an investment that is *very well worth your time*.

The extensive model library that comes with NetLogo itself is under `git` version control and hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/NetLogo/models.

You may also want to take a look at http://modelingcommons.org, which allows for a fairly straightforward tracking of a NetLogo model's history. I'm not sure how much support there is for `.nls` files, however, other than that they can be uploaded as attached files.

Comment: Thanks.  I've gone with git, in part because NetBeans supports it and so I can use github to post my extensions as well.

Answer (score 3):

As for any text document, any version control software (git, subversion, cvs ...) will work just fine for such things :)

Comment: Thanks Robin.  Git seems like the best choice for me.